# Can not filter Date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format in where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bookings table having the following columns:

bookid,facility_id,member_id,start_time,slots. datatype of start_time is timestamp without timezone.

when I use the following query to see all the bookings starting from 2012 September, I am getting some results of 2012 August also.

```
select start_time from cd.bookings
where start_time > '2012-08-31';
```

Sample Result:

```
"2012-08-31 09:00:00"
"2012-08-31 10:30:00"
"2012-08-31 12:00:00"
"2012-08-31 14:30:00"
"2012-08-31 16:30:00"
"2012-08-31 19:00:00"
"2012-08-31 08:00:00"
"2012-08-31 10:30:00"
"2012-08-31 12:00:00"
"2012-08-31 13:30:00"
"2012-08-31 15:00:00"
"2012-08-31 18:30:00"
"2012-08-31 08:30:00"
"2012-08-31 11:00:00"
"2012-08-31 12:30:00"
"2012-08-31 14:00:00"
"2012-08-31 17:00:00"
"2012-08-31 19:00:00"
"2012-08-31 09:00:00"
"2012-08-31 10:30:00"
"2012-08-31 12:30:00"
"2012-08-31 19:30:00"
"2012-08-31 08:30:00"
"2012-08-31 10:00:00"
"2012-08-31 12:30:00"
"2012-08-31 13:30:00"
"2012-08-31 14:30:00"
"2012-08-31 16:30:00"
"2012-08-31 18:00:00"
"2012-08-31 19:00:00"
"2012-08-31 09:30:00"
"2012-08-31 11:00:00"
"2012-08-31 15:00:00"
"2012-08-31 17:00:00"
"2012-08-31 09:00:00"
"2012-08-31 11:00:00"
"2012-08-31 14:30:00"
"2012-08-31 18:00:00"
"2012-08-31 08:00:00"
"2012-08-31 11:30:00"
"2012-08-31 13:00:00"
"2012-08-31 15:00:00"
"2012-08-31 16:30:00"
"2012-08-31 17:30:00"
"2012-08-31 18:30:00"
"2012-08-31 08:30:00"
"2012-08-31 10:00:00"
"2012-08-31 12:30:00"
"2012-08-31 13:30:00"
"2012-08-31 14:00:00"
"2012-08-31 14:30:00"
"2012-08-31 16:00:00"
"2012-08-31 16:30:00"
"2012-08-31 17:00:00"
"2012-08-31 18:00:00"
"2012-08-31 18:30:00"
"2012-08-31 19:00:00"
"2012-08-31 20:00:00"
"2012-09-01 08:00:00"
"2012-09-01 11:00:00"
"2012-09-01 12:30:00"
"2012-09-01 15:00:00"
"2012-09-01 17:00:00"
"2012-09-01 08:00:00"
"2012-09-01 09:30:00"
"2012-09-01 11:00:00"
"2012-09-01 14:30:00"
"2012-09-01 16:30:00"
"2012-09-01 19:00:00"
"2012-09-01 09:00:00"
"2012-09-01 13:30:00"
"2012-09-01 16:30:00"
"2012-09-01 18:00:00"
"2012-09-01 08:30:00"
"2012-09-01 09:30:00"
"2012-09-01 10:30:00"
"2012-09-01 12:30:00"
"2012-09-01 14:00:00"
"2012-09-01 15:00:00"
"2012-09-01 16:30:00" and so on.....
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Since the data type is `timestamp`, the literal `'2012-08-30'` is interpreted as `2012-01-01 00:00:00`. To get only values with a timestamp from Sep 1 or later, use

```
WHERE start_time >= '2021-09-01 00:00:00'
```